# Will users understand this horizontal spin wheel below a number input field?

Tags: usability, input, numbers, spinner

I have implemented a horizontal spin wheel as an additional method to input a number:

[image: Input field with spin wheel below]

You can slide or scroll the measurement left or right and this will change the number in the input field directly ([prototype](https://nekocalc.com/bmi-calculator?alpha)).

Will users understand this? Is it clear enough?

I like to use it, however, the whole interface looks a bit cluttered. How could it be simplified and still understandable? Omit the numbers?

My goal is to have an input field for numeric values that can be changed quickly with and without a keyboard and works for mobile and desktop. A normal slider (instead of the wheel) was no option because they are cumbersome if you want to choose an exact value.

Comment: Your prototype is static for me (Chrome, MacOS). Is it supposed to do something?

Comment: @plainclothes Works for me (same Browser & OS)? So maybe it is really not clear enough :-/ If I hover with the cursor above the measurement and then swipe left and right with two fingers, the numbers change.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, users overwhelmingly prefer the precision and ease of keyboard entry for numbers (and dates and other data that can be specified via number) over "analog-style" controls such as the spinner. This will most definitely be true on the desktop. For mobile, just make sure that you specify an input type that will pop up the calculator/phone-keypad-style number pad, not the full alphanumeric keyboard.

Comment: A situation I was originaly thinking about is when you e.g. jut want to tweak a value from 500 to 510. With the keyboard you have to touch a lot of times. With the wheel it is just one gesture.

Comment: Not that different really. With keyboard input, your example is 5 taps (one to select the field, 3 to input "510", and a final tap to finalize the entry). It is just one gesture, but that gesture requires precision, which is likely to require just as much time as keyboard input, especially for users who don't have precise motor skills.

Answer (score 1):

## Don’t ask us

It all depends on your users. Test it with them. It may be similar to a control they've used before in their line of work. Or totally unfamiliar.

**Ask your users.**

Comment: I see your point. My problem is, I don't have users yet. My plan was to attract them with a good UI.